# How to copy a column from one worksheet to another using the excel javascript api for an excel addin

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

Is there a way to copy a column or a range of cells from one worksheet to another? There are ways to copy ranges of cells within the worksheet, but I am looking to copy cells from one worksheet to another.

I am working with the excel javascript api to create an excel addin.

[The excel javascript api I am using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview?view=excel-js-preview)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This works by passing a range to the copyFrom method.

```
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(function (context) {
    var currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    currentWorksheet.load("name");

    var otherSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add("other-sheet");
    otherSheet.load("name, position");
    var tbACol = currentWorksheet.getRange("A1:A200");
    otherSheet.getRange("A1:A3").copyFrom(tbACol);


    return context.sync().then(function () {
      console.log(`Added worksheet named "${otherSheet.name}" in position ${otherSheet.position}`);
    });
  });
}
```